# What is the C# equivalent for java LinkedList

Tags: c#, java, .net

What is the C# equivalent for java [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: Sorry for being picky, but C# has no list classes at all. The .NET framework has, and different ones depending on the version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use [Linkedlist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) in c# and  this is good example ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {

     // Create a new linked list object instance.

      LinkedList<string> linked = new LinkedList<string>();

    // Use AddLast method to add elements at the end.
    // Use AddFirst method to add element at the start.

      linked.AddLast("cat");
      linked.AddLast("dog");
      linked.AddLast("man");
      linked.AddFirst("first");

    // Loop through the linked list with the foreach-loop.

     foreach (var item in linked)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# already has good `LinkedList` class.

[See msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/he2s3bh7%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Is it not satisfied your requirement?